# How to merge two maps keeping greater of values for matching keys?

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge, scala-collections

I have two mutable maps in Scala.

```
val oldMap = Map(10 -> 100, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 300)
val newMap = Map(10 -> 101, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 299, 40 -> 400)
```

I want to merge `newMap` into `oldMap` to get `outputMap` as below which have all keys from both maps but value is greater of matching key's value.

```
Map(20 -> 200, 40 -> 400, 10 -> 101, 30 -> 300)
```

I have tried below and it works but I wanted to know scala way of doing it.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object Test extends App {

  val oldMap = Map(10 -> 100, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 300)
  val newMap = Map(10 -> 101, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 299, 40 -> 400)
  val outputMap = mergeMap(oldMap, newMap)

  println(outputMap)

  def mergeMap(map1: Map[Int, Int], map2: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {
    val map1Keys = map2.keys
    val itr = map1Keys.iterator
    while (itr.hasNext)
    {
      val id = itr.next
      if (! map1.contains(id)){ // key not present in map1, INSERT
        map1(id) = map2(id)
      }
      else { // key present in map1, UPDATE
        if (map2(id) > map1(id)){
          map1(id) = map2(id)
        }
      }

    }
    map1
  }

  def commonMapKeys[A, B](a: Map[A, B], b: Map[A, B]): scala.collection.Set[A] = a.keySet.intersect(b.keySet)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
newMap.foldLeft(oldMap){ case (result, (k, newV)) =>
  val oldV = result.get(k)
  result + (k -> oldV.fold(newV)(newV max _))
}
```

You start from `oldMap` and iterate through `newMap` using `.foldLeft`. In each iteration you take a key and a value from `newMap`, and try to get the value mapped to the same key from the result map (which is the `oldMap` at the beginning). You add a new mapping from `k` to either the new value, or the max of the new and the old values, in case the old map also contained `k`.

It's pretty much the same thing that you have, just in a more functional way.

Comment: This is working. Can you also explain your answer a bit? I am quite new to Scala programming.

Comment: What if there is key in `oldMap` missing in a new one?

Comment: @GuruStron shouldn't be a problem, if I get it right.
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/k85ZBQryRY2UuZA9uRmFyw

Comment: @conetfun, other than `Iterable.foldLeft()` you need to know `Option.fold()()` that defines a mapping of an optional value. Its first argument is a default value for the case when the optional is `None`. In case the optional value is defined, the value wrapped in `Some()` is passed to the function in the second argument. Here the second argument `newV max _ ` is a function literal and `_` stands for the function's input (i.e. the unwrapped `oldV`)

Comment: @zagyi yes, thank you. Folds still blow my mind sometimes)

Comment: @GuruStron, yep it takes some getting used to, but it's worth the effort, they are very useful and ubiquitous in functional programming.

Comment: Honestly, I had not particular reason to mark one solution as answer as both of them worked fine. I am going with @zagyi solution as it came first.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn maps into collection of tuples, merge them, group by key and select max value in the group:

```
val oldMap = Map(10 -> 100, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 300)
val newMap = Map(10 -> 101, 20 -> 200, 30 -> 299, 40 -> 400)
(oldMap.toSeq ++ newMap.toSeq)
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).max)
```

Or using `groupMapReduce` available since Scala 2.13:

```
(oldMap.toSeq ++ newMap.toSeq)
    .groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(math.max(_,_))
```